# Finding a linear combination of a linear combination of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

**Problem**

Assume $\vec x, \ \vec y$ are linearly independent.

Let $\vec a = 3\vec x + 6\vec y$ and $\vec b = 9 \vec x + 21\vec y$.

Find an expression for $\vec x + \vec y$ as a linear combination of $\vec a, \vec b$.

I.e., find $c_1, \ c_2 \ \in \ \mathbb R$ such that $\vec x + \vec y = c_1\vec a + c_2\vec b$.

**Progress**

I have two different answers from two different methods, and I'm not sure which one is right (if any).

**Method 1**

*(Assume all variables are vectors so I don't have to type \vec a bajillion times.)*

We have the equations

$$\begin{align}
3x + 6y &= a \\
9x + 21y &= b
\end{align}$$

This gives us the coefficient matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 6 & a \\
9 & 21 & b
\end{bmatrix}$$

whose reduction I've found to be

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -\frac53a + \frac23b \\
0 & 1 & -a + \frac13 b
\end{bmatrix}$$

Adding the two rows, we get the equation

$$x+y = -\frac83a + b$$

which is my first attempt.

**Method 2**

This time I used the initial equations

$$\begin{align}
\vec a &= 3x + 6y \\
\vec b &= 9x + 21y\end{align}$$

and found $3a = 9x + 18y$ so that $b-3a = 3y \ \Rightarrow \ y = -a + \frac13b$ by eliminating the $x$ term

and then doing the same with the $y$ term by adding $-\frac72$ of the first equation to the second, giving $x = \frac73 a - \frac32 b$.

Now

$$x+y = \frac43a - \frac76 b$$

which is different from the result of method 1.

**Question**

One (or both) of these must be wrong.

1. Is there a way to verify a potential solution here like we do with regular systems of equations?
2. Which of my methods went awry? I smell careless mistakes in both of them to be honest.

Comment: Substitute in the values of $a$ and $b$ then see if they evaluate to $x+y$ to double check your answer.

Comment: You simply miscalculated in method 1. You could have noticed that after seeing that in method 2, your solution for y was equal to the last row in method 1. Should have double checked then if you got the first row wrong.

Comment: @ManateePink - I did indeed. Found the error now that I knew for sure that it was in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminate the $x$ term in row two by replacing row two with (row two minus three times row one).
$$
\boxed{\begin{align*}
3x + 6y &= a \\
(9x + 21y) - 3(3x + 6y) &= (b) - 3(a)
\end{align*}}
\implies
\boxed{\begin{align*}
3x + 6y &= a \\
3y &= -3a + b
\end{align*}}
$$
Conveniently, the coefficients of $x$ and $y$ will match if we just replace row one with (row one minus row two).
$$
\boxed{\begin{align*}
(3x + 6y) - (3y) &= (a) - (-3a + b) \\
3y &= a - 3b
\end{align*}}
\implies
\boxed{\begin{align*}
3x + 3y &= 4a - b \\
3y &= a - 3b
\end{align*}}
$$
Finally, scale row one by a factor of a third to obtain:
$$
\boxed{\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{3}(3x + 3y) &= \frac{1}{3}(4a - b) \\
3y &= a - 3b
\end{align*}}
\implies
\boxed{\begin{align*}
x + y &= \frac{4}{3}a - \frac{1}{3} b \\
3y &= a - 3b
\end{align*}}
$$
We can check by substitution:
\begin{align*}
\frac{4}{3}a - \frac{1}{3} b
&= \frac{4}{3}(3x + 6y) - \frac{1}{3} (9x + 21y) \\
&= (4x + 8y) + (-3x + -7y) \\
&= x + y
\end{align*}

Comment: Perfect! I had the right idea in method 1, but simply made some arithmetical errors along the way. It's strange how errors like that are completely invisible unless you *know for a fact* that they're there.